# Encadenar operadores ternarios en php laravel

Tags: laravel

El problema que tengo es que solo me toma el ultimo valor y no el que deberia por ejemplo el 4 me esta tomando este es el que me esta tomando $empleado->estado_civil==6?'viudo':'divorciado'

```
<div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::label('certificado', 'Estado Civil:', ['class' => 'col-lg-3 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-8">
{!! Form::text('certificado',$empleado->estado_civil==3?'soltero':'divorciado'||$empleado->estado_civil==4?'casado':'divorciado'||$empleado->estado_civil==6?'viudo':'divorciado', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el certificado']) !!}
    </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres hacerlo encadenando operadores ternarios, seria de esta forma:

```
$empleado->estado_civil == 3 ? ('soltero') : ($empleado->estado_civil == 4 ? ('casado') : ($empleado->estado_civil == 6 ? 'viudo' :'divorciado' ))
```

Pero como consejo, lo suyo seria que tuvieses una tabla en la Base de datos que relacione estado civil con el nombre del estado. Así podrías simplificarte mucho las cosas utilizando relaciones de eloquent.

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono lo unico es que bueno tengo una tabla de empleados donde guardo la informacion y tengo varios radio button donde elige en que estado esta pero seria mucho mejor que creara una tabla aparte de solo estados del empleado donde me guarde el estado de los empleados

Comment: Claro, al tener una tabla relacional, no tendras que hacer ese "codigo" para poder decir el nombre del estado, si no que simplemente se volvera algo tan sencillo como `$empleado->estado_civil->nombre`